# Running multiple filters in Laravel don't work

Tags: php, laravel, filter

I am pretty new to Laravel and have just started to learn it. As I have viewed in several tutorials over the net it is clear to how use more then one filter for a specific route. I have made two filters as below :

```
Route::filter('greeting', function() {  return 'Hello.'; });

Route::filter('farewell', function() {  return 'Goodbye.'; });
```

And the code in the routes.php is as follows:

```
Route::get('greetings', array(
        'before' => array('greeting', 'greeting2'),
        function ()
{
    return 'Welcome newcomer!';
}));
```

I am wondering why the `farewell` filter does not get published and the only result would be that of the `greeting` filter. What have I done wrong here that make my code not to use both filters' results and publish them?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? Filters were deprecated in favour of middleware in Laravel 5.

Comment: I have installed version 4.2.19. Should I Install the newer 5.x version?

Comment: My problem would be if all filters I have put in my code do execute or the Route executes only the one that returns true or the very first one who does so !!!